# How do I use IOB tags with Stanford NER?

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

There seem to be a few different settings:

```
iobtags
iobTags
entitySubclassification (IOB1 or IOB2?)
evaluateIOB
```

Which setting do I use, and how do I use it correctly?

I tried labelling like this:

```
1997    B-DATE
volvo   B-BRAND
wia64t  B-MODEL
highway B-TYPE
tractor I-TYPE
```

But on the training output, it seemed to think that B-TYPE and I-TYPE were different classes.

I am using the 2013-11-12 release.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How this can be done is currently (2013 releases) a bit of a mess, since there are two different sets of flags for two different `DocumentReaderAndWriter` implementations. Sorry.

The most flexible support for different IOB styles is found in `CoNLLDocumentReaderAndWriter`. You can have it map any IOB/IOE/... annotation done by hyphenated prefixes like your examples (B-BRAND) to any other while it is reading files with the flag:

```
-entitySubclassification IOB2
```

The resulting label set is then used for training and classification. The options are documented in the `entitySubclassify()` method of `CoNLLDocumentReaderAndWriter`: IOB1, IOB2, IOE1, IOE2, SBIEO, IO. You can find a discussion of IOB1 vs. IOB2 in [Tjong Kim Sang and Veenstra 1999](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/E/E99/E99-1023.pdf). By default the representation is mapped back to IOB1 on output, since that is the default used in the CoNLL `conlleval` program, but you can keep it as what you mapped it to with the flag:

```
-retainEntitySubclassification
```

To use this `DocumentReaderAndWriter`, you can give a training command like:

```
java8 -mx6g edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop conll.crf.chris2009.prop -readerAndWriter edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.CoNLLDocumentReaderAndWriter -entitySubclassification iob2
```

Alternatively, `ColumnDocumentReaderAndWriter` is the default `DocumentReaderAndWriter` which we use in the distributed models. The options you get with it are different and slightly more limited. You have these two flags:

- `-mergeTags` will take either plain ("BRAND") or CoNLL-like ("I-BRAND") labels and map them down to a prefix-less IO label ("BRAND") and use that for training and classifying.
- `-iobTags` can take either plain ("BRAND") or CoNLL-like ("I-BRAND") labels and maps them to IOB2.

In a sequence model, for any of the labeling schemes like IOB2, the labels **are** different classes. That is how these labeling schemes work. The special interpretation of "I-", "B-", etc. is left to the human observer and entity-level evaluation software. The included evaluation software will work with IOB1, IOB2, or prefixless IO encoding only.

Comment: Prof. Manning, I am curious how the IOB encoding compares with IO encoding as of 2016. I see in 2012 you had said in NLP class: https://youtu.be/mbMrRT5Osbk?t=6m27s