# How to use IOB type of encoding in core-nlp NER

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to train my NER-model with a training set as shown below.

```
British B-company 
Broadcasting    I-company 
Corporation I-company 
British nationality
public  B-orgTpye
service I-orgType
broadcaster I-orgTpye
headquartered   HQ
London  city
Newyork city
American    B-company
Airlines    I-company   
Jaguar  auto
Mercedes    auto
McLaren auto
```

When I run my CRF classifier. It does not recognize B and I's. It considers them as seperate token labels.

Below is my code for the classifier.

```
String[] String2StringArray =  "The British Broadcasting Corporation is a British public service broadcaster headquartered at Broadcasting House in London";   

    Properties props = new Properties();

            String basedir = ModelLocation");
            props.setProperty("ner.model", customModelFile"));
            props.setProperty("ner.model", basedir);
            props.setProperty("ner.combinationMode", "HIGH_RECALL");
            props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "true");
            Property("sutime.includeRange", "true");

            props.setProperty("ner.applyNumericClassifiers", "true");


    StringBuilder classifierOutputAsString = new StringBuilder();
            /*Combining different classifier models*/
            //NERClassifierCombiner classifierCombiner = new NERClassifierCombiner(props);
            NERClassifierCombiner classifierCombiner = new NERClassifierCombiner(true,true,GenericNERModel_A,customModelFile));


            for (String str : String2StringArray) {
                String classifiedToken = classifierCombiner.classifyWithInlineXML(str);
                classifierOutputAsString.append(classifiedToken);       

            }

        System.out.println(classifierOutputAsString.toString());
```

The output is as shown below :

```
The <ORGANIZATION>British Broadcasting Corporation</ORGANIZATION> is a <nationality>British</nationality> <B-orgTpye>public</B-orgTpye> <I-orgType>service</I-orgType> <I-orgTpye>broadcaster</I-orgTpye> <HQ>headquartered</HQ> <city>at</city> <ORGANIZATION>Broadcasting House</ORGANIZATION> in <LOCATION>London</LOCATION>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on a previous answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469082/how-do-i-use-iob-tags-with-stanford-ner) by Christopher Manning. I added these lines to the prop file

```
    props.setProperty("entitySubclassification", "IOB1");
    props.setProperty("retainEntitySubclassification", "true");
    props.setProperty("mergeTags", "true");
```

Now, its uses the IOB type of encoding.

Comment: Thanks. This led me to do a check at :https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/NERFeatureFactory.html