# Get Stanford NER result through NLTK with IOB format

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

i'm using nltk as interface for Stanford NER Tagger. I have question that are there any options to **get NER result as IOB format using NLTK**? I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469082/how-do-i-use-iob-tags-with-stanford-ner) but it's for java user

NLTK version:  3.4

Java version:  jdk1.8.0_211/bin

Stanford NER model:  english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz

**Input**: My name is Donald Trumph

**Expected output**: My/O name/O is/O Donald/B-PERSON Trumph/I-PERSON

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51981566/610569 and https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki/Stanford-CoreNLP-API-in-NLTK

Comment: the main thing is how can i get IOB format with output ?

Comment: See the NER Tagger portion of the answer... Read the answer `ner_tagger = CoreNLPParser(url='http://localhost:9000', tagtype='ner')`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk/51981566#51981566

Comment: I've already seen it, it's only return same tag PERSON for person name, but i want it return it with IOB format: Donald Trumph -> Donald/B-PERSON Trumph/I-PERSON

Comment: Welcome to SO. Next time try to put some effort in explaining what you have tried. Otherwise people will not be responsive here on SO =)

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

First see [Stanford Parser and NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883277/stanford-parser-and-nltk/51981566#51981566)

Write a simple loop and iterate through the NER outputs:

```
def stanford_to_bio(tagged_sent):
    prev_tag = "O"
    bio_tagged_output = []
    current_ner = []
    for word, tag in tagged_sent:
        if tag == 'O':
            bio_tagged_output += current_ner
            bio_tagged_output.append((word, tag))
            current_ner = []
            prev_tag = 'O'
        else:
            if prev_tag == 'O':
                current_ner.append((word, 'B-'+tag))
                prev_tag = 'B'
            else:
                current_ner.append((word, 'I-'+tag))
                prev_tag = 'I'
    if current_ner:
        bio_tagged_output += current_ner
    return bio_tagged_output

tagged_sent = [('Rami', 'PERSON'), ('Eid', 'PERSON'), ('is', 'O'), ('studying', 'O'), ('at', 'O'), ('Stony', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('Brook', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('University', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('in', 'O'), ('NY', 'STATE_OR_PROVINCE')]
stanford_to_bio(tagged_sent)
```

[out]:

```
[('Rami', 'B-PERSON'),
 ('Eid', 'I-PERSON'),
 ('is', 'O'),
 ('studying', 'O'),
 ('at', 'O'),
 ('Stony', 'B-ORGANIZATION'),
 ('Brook', 'I-ORGANIZATION'),
 ('University', 'I-ORGANIZATION'),
 ('in', 'O'),
 ('NY', 'B-STATE_OR_PROVINCE')]
```